# Parallel Redo Is Shutdown

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2016

When looking in Windows event logs, i'm seeing the following messages on an almost continuous basis -

`Starting up database 'Database'.
Parallel redo is started for database 'Database' with worker pool size [1].
Parallel redo is shutdown for database 'Database' with worker pool size [1].`

These messages happen at the same time, and repeat continuously every second.

Can someone explain what Parallel Redo is, and why it's continually starting and stopping, and causing the database to have to restart?

The database is being used by an ASP.NET web application using Entity Framework, running on IIS. Windows Server 2016 Standard and SQL Server 14.0.100 (Sql Server 2017 Express Edition).

Comment: On a recent instance (SQL Server 2017 CU8 Standard Edition) restart, I had one of these messages for each of my user databases in the log. I've never seen it before. I'm curious to see what responses you get.

Comment: Surely someone knows what Parallel redo is??

Comment: Same thing here running mssql-server-Linux:latest in a docker container. Did you ever find any clues as to what causes this?

Answer (score -1):

Try setting auto close to false, this can be done in the option section of the DB properties.

Here's a link to explain this. Someone commented something similar on the thread below.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239181/messages-about-parallel-redo

Comment: To achive ... what?